# ASP.net dropdown list postback dosnot work inside jquery and control panel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, vb.net, internet-explorer-11

I call an asp webpage inside JQuery  code as following :

```
$("#zr_users_edit").click(function () {
        $("#panel-label").text("Edit User Account")
        $("#display-panel").stop().animate({ left: 0 }, 400);
        $("#data-panel").load("index.aspx?ref=users&acts=edit", {}, function (data) {
        });
    });
```

the webpage contains a dropdownlist with auto postback option , when i click and browse it on IE11 i got the following error message :

> Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

the page code as following :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID = "ScriptManager1" OnAsyncPostBackError="ScriptManager1_AsyncPostBackError" runat="server" ></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID = "UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="zr_lb_message" runat="server" Text=" " style="color:Red;padding-left:35%;"></asp:Label>
            <div id ="zr_htm_add" runat="server" visible="False"  style="display:table;float:left;padding-left:35%;margin-right:90px;">
                <br />
                <div class= "div-row" id="zr_htm_edit" runat="server" visible="False">
                    <div class="div-cell">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="zr_dl_users" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" class="dynamicDropDownList" style="width: 119px">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select User:</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div></ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel></form>
```

so is there some thing i missed to do , please help me

Answer (score 0):

I setup your code in my machine but there is no error expect one div end tag is missing.
However, I checked the .load function (its preferable to load html files), I am not sure about aspx.

I would suggest to use different approach.

Thanks
Abhishek